# Wordpress json - How to use the content rendered from json

Tags: rest-api, json

Using Wordpress basic Json in the format //domain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/ I can access to a specific page content.

[image]

What I need to do is to use the rendered content as html of a blank page.

How to store this content in a variable so that I can use it using php? I suppose I should store it first in an array and then use only the content element. Any sample?

Thank you.

Comment: In what context? How and where are you retrieving the JSON? This sounds like a basic PHP question, rather than anything to do with WordPress.

Comment: Basically, I need to build PAGE A using the HTML of the content of public PAGE B which is located on another website. I have an administrator role for both websites. I kind of scraper. Now I'm using php file_get_contents and it works, but wonder if possible to use native Wordpress json
Thank you.